# dart polymer paper-tab - how to dynamically select (and therefore highlight)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using Polymer `paper-tabs` - all working fine.

I want to programmatically select a `paper-tab`, and **show** it as selected/highlighted. Functionally there is no problem, but the tab is not showing "the correct colour" (=as highlighted).

I have used:

```
 PaperTabs mypaperTabs=...

 mypaperTabs.selected = "#mytab';
```

and

```
 myTab.click();
```

The previously selected tab does correctly become unselected. So it is showing as all tabs as unselected. Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the number of the tab to `selected` not the value of the `id` attributed.
For example:

```
mypaperTabs.selected = "1';
```